# RuntimeError: root not bracketed

Tags: python, c++, quantlib

```
class ComputeIV
{
    public:    
        typedef std::pair<SimpleQuote,SimpleQuote> BidAsk;    

        static Volatility ComputeImpliedVol(const Date evalDate, const Date expiration, ptime quoteTime, const Option::Type optionType, 
                  const Real underlyingPrice, const Real optionPrice, const Real strike, const Rate riskFree) 
        {
            ActualActual actualActual;
            Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = evalDate;    

            Time timeToMaturity = actualActual.yearFraction(Settings::instance().evaluationDate(), expiration);

            time_duration timeOfDayDuration = quoteTime.time_of_day();
            timeToMaturity += (timeOfDayDuration.hours() + timeOfDayDuration.minutes()/60.0)/(24.0 * 365.0);               

            DiscountFactor discount = std::exp(-riskFree * timeToMaturity);

            Bisection bisection;
            Real accuracy = 0.000001, guess = .20;
            Real min = .05, max = .40;
            Volatility sigma = bisection.solve([&](const Volatility & sigma) {
                Real stdDev = sigma * std::sqrt(timeToMaturity);
                BlackCalculator blackCalculator(optionType, strike, underlyingPrice, stdDev, discount);
                    return blackCalculator.value() - optionPrice;
            }, accuracy, guess, min, max);  

            return sigma;    

        } 

    static const double& pTest(const std::string evalDateStr, const std::string expirationStr, const std::string quoteTimeStr, 
                               const int optType, const Real forwardBid, const Real forwardAsk, const Rate riskFree, const Real strike, 
                               const Real oBid, const Real oAsk)
    {
        std::cout << "Computing IV" << std::endl << std::flush;
        ActualActual actualActual;

        std::cout << evalDateStr << " " << expirationStr << " " << quoteTimeStr << std::endl << std::flush;
        std::cout << optType << " "  << riskFree << " " << forwardBid << " " << forwardAsk << " " << strike 
                  << " " <<  oBid << " " << oAsk << std::endl << std::flush;

        Date evalDate = DateParser::parseFormatted(evalDateStr.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y");
        Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = evalDate;

        Date expiration = DateParser::parseFormatted(expirationStr.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y");

        ptime quoteTime(from_iso_string(quoteTimeStr));
        time_duration timeOfDayDuration = quoteTime.time_of_day();

        Real price = (oBid + oAsk) / 2.0;    

        Option::Type oType = (optType > 0 ? Option::Call : Option::Put);
        Volatility *sigma = new Volatility();
        *sigma = ComputeIV::ComputeImpliedVol(evalDate, expiration, quoteTime, oType, 
                                forwardAsk, price, strike, riskFree);

        return *sigma;                        
    }

    private:        

};
```

When I call with these parameters,

```
from options import ComputeIV

PUT = -1
Call = 1

evalDate = "03/01/2017"
expiration = "07/07/2017";
quoteTime = "20170103T210000"
forwardBid = 84.19 
forwardAsk = 84.20  
riskFree = .015 
strike = 45.0
oBid = 0.10
oAsk = 0.17
oType = PUT

sigma = ComputeIV.pTest(evalDate, expiration, quoteTime, oType, forwardBid, forwardAsk, riskFree, strike, oBid, oAsk)

print "from python sigma = %f" % sigma
```

I get a runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cboelivedata.py", line 575, in <module>
    main()
  File "cboelivedata.py", line 400, in main
    sigma = ComputeIV.pTest(evalDate, expiration, quoteTime, oType, forwardBid, forwardAsk, riskFree, strike, oBid, oAsk)
RuntimeError: root not bracketed: f[0.05,0.4] -> [-1.350000e-01,-2.434993e-02]
[idf@node3 python]$
```

**Is there something I am not doing correctly here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the Black Formula. In the Black-Scholes framework for European option, the option price is an increasing function of the volatility.

Your minimum and maximum range for your bisection volatility is `0.05` and `0.40`. Are they good enough? Your put option is deep out-of-money, and thus needs a high volatility.

Let's check your range. Goto http://www.erieri.com/blackscholes, and type in the information like how I did:

[image]

The maximum put option price your solver can give you is about 0.0797, but **your quote price is 0.135**. Thus, there is no solution and your bisection root solver is correct to tell you that.

You will need to increase the volatility range. Try:

```
Real min = .05, max = 1.00;
```

You might not need 1.00 (this is too big), but you get the idea - you will need to adjust your root-solving range.

Try it and you will get your implied volatility.

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there correct way to dynamically change the range based on bis/ask of the option, or is it best to just leave it one range for everything?

Comment: @Ivan Leave it to a fixed range and adjust it if you have to.